# Make child element (with padding) 100% width and height of parent

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make a child element (with padding) 100% width and height of its parent element?

html:

```
 <div id="parent">
       <div id="child"></child>
    </div>
```

css:

```
  #child {
    padding: 15px
    }
```

I have tried making the child 100% width/height but this makes the child larger than the parent due to the padding.

I have also tried to make the child position absolute and set top,bottom,left and right to 0 and this works for the width but not the height.

The parent can be a variable size.

In addition needs to work on IE8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`box-sizing: border-box;` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

```css
#child {
    padding: 15px
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Box sizing property

You can use the `box-sizing` property for that.
like this :

```
#child{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:15px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/8kQ5z/)**

This property includes the padding (and border if you have some) to the total width of the child so it won't overflow the container even if you set `width:100%;` and give it some padding.

More info about this property on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

This property is supported by IE8+ but you will need the `-moz-` prefix to support FF28- see [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing) for more info.

### % padding

If you can use percent padding, you can do this calculation so the child element has the same size as the parent without the `box-sizing` property.

Calculation for the width :

```
width of child +  left and right padding child = 100%
```

Calculation for the height :

```
height of child +  top and bottom padding child = 100%
```

example :

```
#child {
    padding: 5%;
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/8kQ5z/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the box model to use `box-sizing: border-box;`

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You may need to use http://modernizr.com/ for support with IE8.

[**Compatibility Table for box-sizing**](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-box)

Comment: as the compatibility table you link to says, no need for modernizr for IE8 support.