# Child elements don't get 100% of parent's width and height even with box-sizing set to border-box?

Tags: html, css

**EDIT: Not a duplicate of:**

[Make child element (with padding) 100% width and height of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825664/make-child-element-with-padding-100-width-and-height-of-parent)

In that question, the person was in need of the `box-sizing: border-box` model. I already got that model on my snippet.

What I'm trying to wrap my head around is the fact that, when you're using the `border-box` model with padding and/or border set to the parent, a child with 100% of height/width will only inherit the content-box height/width of the parent, and not the proper height/width (element's inspected height/width) itself. Because if you inspect the parent in my snippet, you'll see height/width set to 100px. And the child will be 80px. So, how come 100% of a height/width of 100px could be equal to 80px? That was counter-intuitive for me, but I think the answer is on the bold parts of the MDN quote below.

[image: ParentDiv]

[image: ParentHeight]

[image: ChildDiv]

[image: ChildHeight]

[MDN Source: box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

> By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an
>   element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element
>   has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height
>   to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen. This
>   means that when you set width and height, you have to adjust the value
>   you give to allow for any border or padding that may be added.
>
> The **box-sizing** property can be used to adjust this behavior:
>
> **content-box** gives you the default CSS box-sizing behavior. If you set
>   an element's width to 100 pixels, then the element's content box will
>   be 100 pixels wide, and the width of any border or padding will be
>   added to the final rendered width.
>
> **border-box** tells the browser to
>   account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an
>   element's width and height. If you set an element's width to 100
>   pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or padding you added,
>   and **the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width.** This
>   typically makes it much easier to size elements.

---

**Original Question**

I've been faced with a situation where a child element's `width` and `height` are set to 100% of the parent's width and `height`. And I'm using `box-sizing: border-box;`

Can somebody explain why that happens?

[From MDN Docs on box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), we get that:

> border-box tells the browser to account for any border and padding in
>   the values you specify for an element's width and height. If you set
>   an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any
>   border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb
>   that extra width. This typically makes it much easier to size
>   elements.

So in the following snippet, I was expecting that the child would cover completely the parent, because it would have `width` and `height` set to 100% of the parent. But that is not the case. The child gets 100% of the parent's `height` and `width` **minus** `border` and `padding`.

**Question**

If you inspect the elements (rendered by the snippet) you'll see that the parent `height` and `width` is 100px and the child is only 80px. Shouldn't it be also 100px, since it's set to 100%? Why this happens?

100% of the height is only related to the content box?

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
const child = document.getElementById('childDiv');

const parentStyle = window.getComputedStyle(parent);
const childStyle = window.getComputedStyle(child);

document.getElementById('description1').innerHTML = 'The parent height is: ' + parentStyle.height;
document.getElementById('description2').innerHTML = 'The child height is: ' + childStyle.height;

document.getElementById('description3').innerHTML = 'The parent width is: ' + parentStyle.width;
document.getElementById('description4').innerHTML = 'The child width is: ' + childStyle.width;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#parentDiv {
  border: 5px dotted black;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  
}

#childDiv {
  background-color:blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv">
  <div id="childDiv"></div>
</div>
<h3>Height</h3>
<div id="description1"></div>
<div id="description2"></div>
<h3>Width</h3>
<div id="description3"></div>
<div id="description4"></div>
```

Comment: you are using 5px padding to your #parentdiv

Comment: put box-sizing: border-box in the * {} css selector to apply it to every element

Comment: The child **is** 100% of parent, though its _content box_ is not, as with `box-sizing: border-box;`, padding and border is **included** in the set _width/height_. This will, in your case, make the _content box_ 80px wide/high. (100px - (5px border + 5px padding * 2))

Comment: @LGSon I've edited and explained why I think this is not a duplicate. See that using the `border-box` model and looking in `height` and `width` numbers only, it's completely counter-intuitive that your child div only gets the `height` and `width` of the parent `content-box` which has shrunk to 80px behind the scenes because of the `border-box` property.

Comment: `border-box tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height.` --> any border and padding that belong to the element not the parent of the element so the child will be smaller than its parent

Comment: added another duplicate to better explain this. It's about position absolute (so padding-box) but the same logic apply. TL;DR from all this is that padding/border of the parent has nothing to do in the width/height of the child

Comment: @TemaniAfif I understood that. I just think this is counter-intuitive (since you can inspect the parent and see the full height and width that is not fully passed down to the child) and this question helps people to be aware of this better than the other ones. Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: it's indeed intuitive, imagine your self inside a house with walls, when you will add some furnitures inside, will you account for the width of the walls? no you won't because it doesn't make sense. you are inside the house and the space offred to you is the space without the wall. But if you want to know the width/height of the house you have to include the walls because they are a part of the house